# iOS : Pass message to different labels in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I have six labels in a view controller and I get six strings in a for loop as follows.

```
for(NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
{
     NSString *name = dictionary[@"Name"];
     NSLog(@"Name = %@ \n", name);
}
```

Whenever I get a name in log, I want to send that name in different labels' (six of them) to a view controller.

how to pass the name object/message to a label? You get different names/results for each iteration and pass those iterated value to a label

Get 1st name in for loop, post to label 1.

Get 2nd name in for loop, post to label 2
and so on..

Comment: I can' understand correctly wt you are saying. Can please tell me some wt briefly?

Comment: how to pass the name object/message to a label? You get different names/results for each iteration and pass those iterated value to a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *lbls = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6, nil];

int i=0;
for(NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
{
     UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[lbls objectAtIndex:i++];
     [lbl setText:dictionary[@"Name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map of the name to the corresponding `UILabel` element:

YourClass.h:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController {
    NSMutableDictionary *_labelMap;
    IBOutlet UILabel *_label1;   // Connected in IB
    IBOutlet UILabel *_label2;   // Connected in IB
    IBOutlet UILabel *_label3;   // Connected in IB
    IBOutlet UILabel *_label4;   // Connected in IB
    IBOutlet UILabel *_label5;   // Connected in IB
    IBOutlet UILabel *_label6;   // Connected in IB
}
```

...

YourClass.m:

```
@implementation YourClass {

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Not done in init, as you need the labels to be connected once the NIB is loaded
    _labelMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    _labelMap[@"Name1"] = _label1;
    _labelMap[@"Name2"] = _label2;
    _labelMap[@"Name3"] = _label3;
    _labelMap[@"Name4"] = _label4;
    _labelMap[@"Name5"] = _label5;
    _labelMap[@"Name6"] = _label6;
    ...
}

- (void)yourMethod {
    for(NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
    {
        NSString *name = dictionary[@"Name"];
        NSLog(@"Name = %@", name);    // Don't need to add newline!
        UILabel *field = _labelMap[name];
        field.text = name;
    }
}
```